# Brief higher voltage on one leg lower on other every sixty seconds or so

Tags: electrical

Could this be caused by a electrical utility meter resetting on a poor neutral meter box connection?

About once every sixty seconds or so I'll get 5 more volts on one side and about 8 volts less on the other. It just keeps happening over and over that you could almost set your watch to this. Ill get stable current well maybe within two or three volts, then for three seconds this condition will occur then go back to stable current again. Over and over. I don't have a meter capable of checking distribution line voltage so I cannot check if a substation issue like with a protective relay or something but I'm  getting this condition on the secondary side and its doing it on more than one meter in a bank of meters. Linemen have changed out the pole transformer, and done a bit of neutral line work and this condition still persists.

Comment: What 120V load inside your home is turning on/off those times? Neighbor's home? Can you watch the meters to see when the disc lunges forward?

Comment: This isn't from a load in the house, as I said every sixty seconds at more then one meter. Neighbors house not sure but it is every miniute for days this has been going on , The other meter I checked no one living there other no volt draw. This was from Poster Jim H

Comment: Have you called the power company ?  If it’s a burnt connection arcing and affecting multiple customers it’s likely right at the transformer.  When you say “utility meter resetting” what exactly do you mean?  Do the lights in your house flicker *brighter*? That is a sure sign of a utility neutral problem.

Comment: Is it always the same legs that misbehave? Are you on a 120/240V split phase service, or a 120/208V 2-out-of-3 service?  Is this causing an actual issue within the house?

Comment: From the information you are giving us, I can say that there is a low probability that the problem is a neutral. More than likely it is a branch hitting the distribution or perhaps a bad insulator.  Regardless it is a utility problem and needs to be resolved by them. If you have taken readings at multiple residences and have witnesses, I would contact your utility provider and make arrangements to meet with them and demonstrate the problem.